# Understanding Matrix Norms

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm trying to gain intuition for matrix norms. I'd like to know why if $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that $||A||$ is equal to both $\max _{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$ and $\max_{||x||=1}||Ax||$. Why are these two definitions equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe for any $x \neq 0$, we have that 
\begin{align}
\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \left\| A\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\| = \|A v\|
\end{align}
where $v$ is a unit vector.

Comment: Why is the first equality true?

Comment: Because $\| \, \cdot \, \|$ is a norm and $(1/\| x\|)$ is a scalar.

Comment: Is this definition also equivalent to $||A||=\max_{||x||<1}\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$?

Comment: By the scaling argument, the definitions are the same.

Comment: So basically by dividing the numerator and denominator by $||x||$?